# CustomDrawer in Flutter with default Value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm very new to Flutter. I'm trying to build a CustomDrawer class which can be imported and customized as needed.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

      class CustomDrawer extends AppBar {
            CustomDrawer ({ Key key, Widget leading, Widget title}) 
                      : super(key: key, leading: leading, title: title, actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.notifications_none),
            onPressed: () => print("Hello World"),
          ),
        ]);
}
```

I want the leading Widget to display the default text "Placeholder" when no parameter is provided, else leading should display whatever was passed to CustomDrawer.
Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple ternary operator can solve this.

build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      /// You can try either of these.
      appBar: CustomDrawer(),
      appBar: CustomDrawer(leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),),
    );
  }
```

CustomDrawer:

```
class CustomDrawer extends AppBar {
  CustomDrawer({
    Key key,
    Widget leading,
    Widget title,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          /// Adding ternary operator.
          leading: leading == null ? Placeholder() : leading,
          title: title,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_none),
              onPressed: () => print("Hello World"),
            ),
          ],
        );
}
```